# How to handle variables in jquery plugins the right (perfect) way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-plugins

I searched a lot, but im still not sure, which is the best way to do what i want.
I'm writing a jQuery plugin and it already worked but now i want to improve my code, because i got to know a lot more functions while writing this.

As a basis i took the code from the official jQuery page http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring (Plugin Options)

I wont use my own code here because the code from jQuery is already enough for my question

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
      var defaults = {
        value1: '',
        value2: ''
       };
       var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
       return this.each(function(){
         value3 = $(this).parent();
       });
    },
    log : function( ) {
      console.log(value3);
      console.log(defaults.value1);
    }
  };

  $.fn.my_plugin = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

This is how my plugin is structured. It's just very stripped now ;)
Now I want to do somethin like this:

```
$('#element1').my_plugin({value1 : 1, value2 : 2});
$('#element2').my_plugin({value1 : 3, value2 : 4});
```

Now i want to log the values in the console (Not exactly what i want to do in real, but for my question it's enough again)

Further I want to use functions like this

```
$('#element1').my_plugin('log');
$('#element2').my_plugin('log');
```

Here is my first Problem. How can i get the variables from the init-function, when im in the log-function? What's the best way to do that?

I tried to set the values global like this:

```
(function( $ ){
  var defaults = {
    value1: '',
    value2: ''
  };
  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { 
       return this.each(function(){
         value3 = $(this).parent();
       });
    },
    log : function( ) {
      console.log(value3);
      console.log(defaults.value1);
    }
  };
```

But if i do this and use `$('#element1').my_plugin('log');`, I only get the defaults from the second init `$('#element2').my_plugin({value1 : 3, value2 : 4});`

So here is my second question: How can i use specific variables for each init?

I hope it's clear, what i want to know. I'm still learning jQuery and giving my best and searched a lot how to solve my problem for this structure. I would like to use this structure, because it's the official one from jquery and i love doing things right :P

Would like too see some answers here soon :)
Thanks for your help,
Julian

If someones interessted into a basic plugin structure - Here is what i use for my plugins now :)

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {
        console.log('init');
      var defaults = {
        value1: '',
        value2: ''
      };
      var options = $.extend(defaults, options);        
      return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('test');
        var parent = $this.parent();
        var element = $this;

        if (!data) {
            var data = {};
            $.each(options, function(key, value) {
                data[key] = value;
            });
            data["parent"] = parent;
            data["element"] = element;
                    $this.data('test', data);
        }

        $this.test('log');

       });
    },

    log : function() {
        console.log('log');
        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('test');
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn.test = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test' );
    }    
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $.data, if you want to keep "this" clean.

Comment: You mean like this:
`$('#element1').data('values', { value1: '1', value3: '3' });`

I thought of that, but i thought there would be a more elegant way to do this. Did not see this very often in other plugins - on the other hand the most plugins do not need functions like $('element').my_plugin('log') and only use the structure like the one from David

Comment: Seems to be the best way. Thank you